# Proof attempt at $\sqrt{4} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to self study Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra, and Topology out of private interest.
I'm working on the exercises in the text, ' Understanding Analysis ' and will be posting my attempts at proving the various theorems in the text.

Hopefully this is ok:

Question 1: Prove that the $\sqrt{4} \in \mathbb{Q}$

**Proof:**

Assume that$ \sqrt{4} = \frac{a}{b}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now,

Clearly by algebraic manipulation,

$\sqrt{4} = \frac{a}{b} \Rightarrow  4=\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}$: equation.1.2

Now, Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of all numbers that can be reduced to the ratio of two integers,

$a,b \in K$; $K$ of course being the set of all odd integers.

Now,

Since $a,b$ are odd integers than they can be defined as,

$ a=2n+1$

$b=2m+1$

Where, $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Substituting $2n+1,2m+1$ into equation 1.2.

- $4=\frac{(2n+1)^{2}}{(2m+1)^{2}} \Rightarrow 4(2m+1)^{2}=(2n+1)^2$

  $\Rightarrow 16m^2+16m+4=4n^2+4n+1n\Rightarrow n=\frac{1}{2}(4m+1):m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Since, $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$  for $\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{4}$.

$\sqrt{4} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

**Q.E.D**

Comment: Why can't you just say that $\sqrt{4} = 2 \in \Bbb Q$?

Comment: If $a,b$ are odd, then you should write $a = 2n+1$ and $b = 2m+1$, not $a = n+1$ and $b = m+1$.

Comment: The proof doesn't make any sense at all. You assume that $\sqrt{4}=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, then you do something, and then you end up by saying that $\sqrt{4}=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ shows that $\sqrt{4}\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Your first step is "Assume that$ \sqrt{4} = \frac{a}{b}:a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$." Is that not essentially what you are trying to prove?

Comment: Most likely he was trying to use the same structure of the proof that $\sqrt{2} \not\in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Even though the 'attempted proof' is being torn apart: I'm glad I posted it. I'm still learning how to approach these sort of problems. I do appreciate the feedback.

Comment: ... and don't try to remove the contents of your post, it won't work. Just move on.

Comment: Is there anyway you can delete it?, I am embarrassed by my post and would like to just, get rid of it.

Comment: @Null: Questions with upvoted answers shouldn't be deleted.  That would be incredibly disrespectful to those who've taken the time to answer.  You can, however, request disassociation from the post by flagging for a moderator.

Comment: @Null you can flag your own question, choose "Other" and ask to dis-associate it from your account, explaining why. This way the question author would appear as anonymous and won't be linked to you.

Comment: @Null, you shouldn't be embarassed by the post, though. Really.

Comment: The system flagged this for the number of comments. I did some pruning - removing duplicates and such. Sorry all, if I did a bad job.

Answer (score 7):

Your proof is incorrect. In particular, you assume $a$ and $b$ are odd, yet this is false - $a$ *must* be even if $\left(\frac{a}b\right)^2=4.$ However, the proof salvages itself when you write the definition of an odd number incorrectly - the property that $a=n+1$ is true of *all* integers, not just odd ones. For instance $4=3+1$, but $4$ is even. But, at the end, you reach the result that
$$\frac{-k-1}{2k+2}=\sqrt{4}.$$
for any $k$, which is pretty close to true (you get $m$ and $n$ mixed up somewhere - so the fraction is upside-down - and for some reason, you get the negative root, but not the positive). Also, as a structural issue, your proof actually shows that if $\sqrt{4}=\frac{a}b$, then $a=2k+2$ and $b=k+1$ for integer $k$, which is true - but you actually need the converse of that (i.e. that if $a=2k+2$ and $b=k+1$, then $\sqrt{4}=\frac{a}b$), since you've otherwise started with the assumption that $\sqrt{4}$ is rational.

Writing $2^2=4$ would be a far more convincing argument that $\sqrt{4}$ is rational.

Comment: $\frac{-k-1}{2k+2}=\sqrt{4}$ is not just upside down. $\sqrt4$ is not a negative number. But the worst part of the proof is the initial assumption that $\sqrt4$ is the quotient of two integers, because that’s what needs to be shown, not assumed.

Comment: Two wrongs don't make a right; but three rights make a left.

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental problem here appears to be that you are trying 
to use the mechanisms you saw in another proof 
(probably the proof that $\sqrt2 \not\in \mathbb Q$).
But since you are trying to prove that $\sqrt4$ *is* rational,
whereas the other proof was trying to prove that a number is *not* rational,
the mechanisms you need are mostly opposite the ones you found in the other proof.

For example, to prove that $\sqrt2 \not\in \mathbb Q$,
a good first step is to write $\sqrt2 = \frac ab$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.
The idea is that you will derive a contradiction from this assumption,
thereby proving that the assumption was false.
But when you assume $\sqrt4 = \frac ab$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$,
that's a true statement; you will not be able to disprove it by
deriving a contradiction or by any other means.

To prove $\sqrt4 \in \mathbb Q$ by contradiction, you could assume first of all
that $\sqrt4 \neq \frac ab$ for every $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.
Conversely, you could assume that there do not exist any $a,b \in \mathbb Z$
such that $\sqrt4 = \frac ab$.
But in either case, you will be unable to proceed with the next step of the
$\sqrt2$ proof, which requires you to have an equation involving $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.
Or if you do proceed with the next step, you will be doing something incorrectly.

In a broader sense, proofs of existence and proofs of non-existence tend to
rely on very different mechanisms. The difference between $\in$ and $\not\in$ is vast.